# My notifications are wrong!

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

I've been getting notifications in my SE inbox as normal, but the counts included are wrong.  In particular I got a notification on my TPK question that says I have five answers, but I only have three.  I'm fairly certain this isn't a quirk of *deleted* because I'm a mod and I see no deleted answers.

[image: Notifier Drop Down ScreenShot]

What is going on here?

Comment: We are cleaning out old bug reports.  Is this still an issue?

Comment: I haven't noticed it in quite a while @geoff

Comment: Going to status-complete this one - report it again if it becomes an issue.